# Small recursive script in go to clone all projects in a Group

Tags: recursion, go

I've just created a small script to clone all projects within a Gitlab Group and all Subgroups inside it.

As I am trying to level up my Go skills, I would welcome any reviews and enhancement on my code.

`clone.go`

```golang
package gl

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/user"
    "strconv"
    "sync"

    "github.com/xanzy/go-gitlab"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
    gitgo "gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4"

    "gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4/plumbing/transport"
    gitgoSSH "gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4/plumbing/transport/ssh"
)

// getSshKeyAuth read private key and return AuthMethod
func getSshKeyAuth(privateSshKeyFile string) transport.AuthMethod {
    var auth transport.AuthMethod
    sshKey, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(privateSshKeyFile)
    signer, _ := ssh.ParsePrivateKey([]byte(sshKey))
    auth = &gitgoSSH.PublicKeys{User: "git", Signer: signer}
    return auth
}

// GroupCloneAllProjects clones all gitlab projects in the given group and it's subgroups
func GroupCloneAllProjects(groupID, key string) {

    log.SetFlags(log.LstdFlags | log.Lshortfile)

    token, empty := os.LookupEnv("GITLAB_PRIVATE_TOKEN")

    if !empty {
        log.Fatal("There is no private token. Please set 'GITLAB_PRIVATE_TOKEN' environment variable")
    }

    git, err := gitlab.NewClient(token)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create client: %v", err)
    }

    var cloneProjects func(groupID, fullPath string, wg *sync.WaitGroup)
    var searchSubgroups func(groupID string)

    // clone all projects in a given group
    cloneProjects = func(groupID, fullPath string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {

        defer wg.Done()

        opt := &gitlab.ListGroupProjectsOptions{}
        projects, _, err := git.Groups.ListGroupProjects(groupID, opt)

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)

        }

        usr, err := user.Current()

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)

        }

        for _, i := range projects {
            fmt.Printf("Cloning %s into %s \n", i.Path, fullPath)

            repoLocalPath := fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s\n", fullPath, i.Path)

            _, err := gitgo.PlainClone(repoLocalPath, false, &gitgo.CloneOptions{

                Auth:     getSshKeyAuth(usr.HomeDir + key),
                URL:      i.SSHURLToRepo,
                Progress: os.Stdout,
            })

            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)

            }

        }

    }

    // get all subgroups within a given group and create matching local directories.
    searchSubgroups = func(groupID string) {

        var wg sync.WaitGroup

        opt := &gitlab.ListSubgroupsOptions{}
        groups, _, err := git.Groups.ListSubgroups(groupID, opt)

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)

        }

        for _, i := range groups {
            os.MkdirAll(i.FullPath, os.ModePerm)

            searchSubgroups(strconv.Itoa(i.ID))

            wg.Add(1)
            go cloneProjects(strconv.Itoa(i.ID), i.FullPath, &wg)
        }

        wg.Wait()

    }

    searchSubgroups(groupID)

}
```

`main.go`

```golang
package main

import (
    gl "blinchikgit/gitlab"
    "flag"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    glclone := flag.Bool("gl", false, "gl clone Gitlab projects under a specific group")
    flag.Parse()

    if *glclone {
        gl.GroupCloneAllProjects(os.Args[2], os.Args[3])
    }

}
```

**run command**

```
go run main.go -gl "id" "/.ssh/yourkey"
```

[source code](https://github.com/blinchik/git)